# Is $S=\left\{ \left( \frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{m} \right) \mid m,n \in \mathbb{N}\right\} \subset \mathbb{R^2} $ open or closed?

Tags: real-analysis

consider the following set:
$$
S=\left\{ \left( \frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{m} \right) \mid m,n \in \mathbb{N}\right\} \subset \mathbb{R^2}
$$

Showing Open:
considering the complement of S, one can write it as the Cartesian product of the union of open intervals as follows:

$$
\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} F_{n}$$
$$\bigcup\limits_{m=1}^{\infty} G_{m}$$
Where we define F and G as follows:
$$
F_{n}=\big( \frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n} \big) \\
G_{m}=\big( \frac{1}{m+1},\frac{1}{m} \big)
$$

The union of an arbitrary collection of open sets is open, therefore both unions defined above are open. Taking the cartesian product we get the complement of S. Since cartesian products preserve openness, we conclude the complement of S is normal, therefore, S is closed

HOWEVER, S does not contain its accumulation points (0,1),(0,0),(1,0), therefore it cannot be closed. I'm confused

Comment: Is $S$ a set of points or intervals?

Comment: Points, it is a subset of R^2. Fixed

Comment: Then it is nor open nor closed. It is not open because there are points which have no open nhood in $S$, for example $(1,1)$. It is not closed since it does not contain some of its limit points, as $(0,0)$.

Comment: Thank you, that makes complete sense, though I am slightly confused as to where my proof logic above fails regarding my construction of the product. May you please look into it and see where perhaps theres an error in my understanding of the theory

Comment: Ok. But first, I don't understand what you are doing. You assert $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus S=F\times G$ with $F=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}F_n$ and $G=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} G_n$?

Answer (score 1):

The set $$\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} F_{n} \times \bigcup\limits_{m=1}^{\infty} G_{m}$$ is not your complement, it only contains the points in the first quadrant.

Your complement is actually 
$$\left(\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty F_n \times \mathbb{R}\right) \cup \left(\mathbb{R}\times \bigcup_{m=0}^\infty G_m\right) \bigcup ( (- \infty , 0] \times \mathbb R ) \bigcup ([0, \infty ) \times (- \infty , 0])\bigcup (1, \infty) \times \mathbb R \bigcup  \mathbb R \times(1, \infty)$$

**P.S.** Your answer would be correct if your set was a subset of $$( 0 , 1] \times (0, 1]$$, and the set is indeed closed in this space. If you also set $F_0, G_0$ as Julian suggested, then the set is closed in $(0, \infty)^2$.

Comment: This was the best answer I could have hoped for. Thank you. One more question, if I may, would it also be correct to conclude no elements in the set S are cluster points. In general for not closed sets this is not true, but is such true for this set

Comment: $(1,1)$ is not a cluster point. Did you mean $(0,0)$?

Comment: This still isn't quite correct.  The easiest way I see to correct it is to first define $F_0=G_0 = (1,\infty)$ and then replace $$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty F_n \times \bigcup_{m=1}^\infty G_m$$ with $$\left(\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty F_n \times \mathbb{R}\right) \cup \left(\mathbb{R}\times \bigcup_{m=0}^\infty G_m\right).$$

Comment: @JulianVillaquirá yes I immediately changed it when i realized my dumb error. Anyway is such a statement true? thank you

Comment: Every point of the form $\left( \frac{1}{n} , 0\right) $ or $\left( 0 ,\frac{1}{n}\right)$ for a fixed $n$ is a limit point. Since $a_m=\left(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{m}\right)$ (resp. $a_m=\left(\frac{1}{m},\frac{1}{n}\right)$) converges to it.

Comment: @JulianVillaquirá TY, fixed (I think). I had $F_0, G_0$ in the back of my mind but missed that the OP started at 1.

Comment: The $F_0, G_0$ was only half of the fix I was talking about.  To reiterate the point with an example, note that $\left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{\pi}\right) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus S.$  Is $\left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{\pi}\right)$ in your proposed set?

Comment: @BrianMoehring ty, need more coffee before posting :)